# Responsive horizontal timeline - Boostrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, timeline

I am trying to make responsive horizontal timeline. I am using Boostrap 4 for timeline and project. So far I have come up with this code and it's working fine when it comes to responsiveness.

**timeline.html**

```
<div className="container timeline-container">
                    <div class="intro">
                        <div class="main-heading">
                            <div class="three-col top">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="sub-heading">
                                        <div class="square">
                                            <div class="pic">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="sub-heading">
                                        <div class="square">
                                            <div class="pic">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="sub-heading">
                                        <div class="square">
                                            <div class="pic">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-heading">
                            <div class="three-col bottom">
                                <div className="wrapper-bottom">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="timeline-dot"> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sub-heading">
                                            <div class="square">
                                                <div class="pic">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="timeline-dot"> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sub-heading">
                                            <div class="square">
                                                <div class="pic">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="timeline-dot"> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sub-heading">
                                            <div class="square">
                                                <div class="pic">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**style.css**

```
.container.timeline-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .intro {
    position: relative;
  }

  .square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 25px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .pic {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -25px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .timeline-dot {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #CF4532;
    margin-top: -6px;
  }

  .main-heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .three-col.bottom{
    border-top: 2px solid #4A4A4A;
  }

  .three-col:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
  }

  .three-col .col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .sub-heading {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0;

  }
```

My timeline looks like this:

[image]

There is two things I would like to change:

1) Remove line before first and after last dot so timeline looks like this
[image]

2) To make picture squares responsive.

I have tried it by making parent `div` like

```
.sub-heading {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;   
}
```

And picture square

```
.square {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 25px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

But it's not working. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can achive that with css `::after` pseudo class on every column. Remove the border top from `.three-col.bottom` and add the border to every `.col` of the top row with `::after`.

Please note the css:

```
.three-col.top .col::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4A4A4A;
}

.three-col.top .col:first-child::after {
  left: 50%;
}

.three-col.top .col:last-child::after {
  right: 50%;
}
```

2) Remove the square div, you don't need it. Also change your .pic style to

```
.pic {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 25px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

For responsive design you need to use css media queries

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp.

So you could try something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .pic {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .pic {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .pic {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Full Code:

```css
.container.timeline-container{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .intro {
      position: relative;
    }

    .square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 25px;
      transform:rotate(45deg);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .pic {
      background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      margin: 25px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .timeline-dot {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #CF4532;
      margin-top: -6px;
    }

    .main-heading {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .three-col:after {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      content: '';
    }

    .three-col .col {
      float: left;
      width: 33.33%;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }

    .sub-heading {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 35px 0;

    }

    .three-col.top .col::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background: #000;
      display: block;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #4A4A4A;
    }

    .three-col.top .col:first-child::after {
      left: 50%;
    }

    .three-col.top .col:last-child::after {
      right: 50%;
    }

    @media (min-width: 576px) {
      .pic {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      .pic {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      .pic {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .pic {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div className="container timeline-container">
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="main-heading">
        <div class="three-col top">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="sub-heading">
              <div class="pic">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="sub-heading">
              <div class="pic">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="sub-heading">
              <div class="pic">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-heading">
        <div class="three-col bottom">
          <div className="wrapper-bottom">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="timeline-dot">
              </div>
              <div class="sub-heading">
                <div class="pic">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <div class="timeline-dot">
              </div>
              <div class="sub-heading">
                <div class="pic">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="timeline-dot">
              </div>
              <div class="sub-heading">
                <div class="pic">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, with pseudo class is really working. And do you have any idea how could I fix second thing from my question `2) To make picture squares responsive`? I have tried it with code above but my squares just loose their shape. With above code I tried to make parent div have fixed width and height of 400px and just apply for child div width and height of 100%. But not working.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "To make picture squares responsive"?

Comment: I just want to make this picture squares or diamond shape to be responsive for all screens.

Comment: Please give some more info, I can't understand what do you mean..You want to change the width and height of squares? You want to change the layout on mobile? An example could help. The responsive looks good on desktop.

Comment: Okay sorry didn't explained that well maybe. Yes I would like my pictures to be bigger or smaller depending on which device they are displayed. When I try to make them bigger by changing `width/height` shape is lost. Yes, on desktop is okay although I would like them to be bigger and I can't figure how :/

Comment: Thanks mate! Update of your answer is just what I was looking for!